# How to replace only one url from many on a pdf in Java, preferably with PdfBox

Tags: java, url, pdf, replace, pdfbox

I am writing a Java application that will loop through a PDF file, find and replace a specific URL and replace the last bit (called **oldreportid**) of it with a new one (called **newreportid**), both are being passed as a parameter.

Eg.:

This:
http://www.test/test.php?T=MQ==&F=**NzQ2**

will become this:
http://www.test/test.php?T=MQ==&F=**XXXX**

I have written most part of the code but I am stuck.

The code below is looping through the PDF File, finding all URLs and replacing all of them with the **newreportid**. This is not the desired result, I only want it to replace the URL that contain the **oldreportid**:

```
public class Helper {


public static void getURL(String oldreportid, String newreportid, String oldpdf, String newpdf) {
    PDDocument doc = null;

    try {
        doc = PDDocument.load(oldpdf);
        List allPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        for (int i = 0; i < allPages.size(); i++) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);
            List annotations = page.getAnnotations();
            for (int j = 0; j < annotations.size(); j++) {
                PDAnnotation annot = (PDAnnotation) annotations.get(j);
                if (annot instanceof PDAnnotationLink) {
                    PDAnnotationLink link = (PDAnnotationLink) annot;
                    PDAction action = link.getAction();
                    if (action instanceof PDActionURI) {
                        PDActionURI uri = (PDActionURI) action;
                        String oldURL = uri.getURI();

                        String reportID = oldURL.substring(oldURL.lastIndexOf("=") + 1, oldURL.length());
                        //System.out.println("a " + reportID);
                        String newURI = "http://www.test.com/test.php?T=MQ==&F=" + newreportid;
                        //System.out.println("Page " + (i + 1) + ": Replacing " + oldURL + " with " + newURI);
                        //if (reportID == oldreportid)

                        uri.setURI(newURI);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        doc.save(newpdf);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (COSVisitorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (doc != null) {
            try {
                doc.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

So the question is, how to make it so it only changes the URL that contains the **oldreportid**?

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to replace the parameter in the String.

```
String oldId = "1234Old";
String newId = "4321New";

String newString = oldURL.replaceAll("(&F=)" + Pattern.quote(oldId) + "(&|$)", "$1" + newId + "$2");
```

The above regular expression will match a parameter of **&F=oldId**

Pattern.quote() escapes the oldId in case it contains RegEx control characters.

The (&|$) pattern makes sure that the parameter stops after oldId - it must be either an ampersand (denoting the start of the next parameter) or the end of the URI String.

Comment: Great answer!! Works and it's well explained!

Updated the OP with the working code. Cheers!